# Is there something wrong with facebook sdk 4.x?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying to get the user email in two different apps and I always get empty response. My colleague has the same issue and online I can only find older versions of response.

I understand that Facebook doesn't guarantee that one can always successfully retrieve the user email, but I tested on different facebook users and got the same response.

I'd appreciate a little help, even a confirmation that my code is not incorrect.

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/me",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                            trace("GRAPH RESPONSE" + response.getJSONObject().toString()); // returns {name:{}, id{}}

                                String token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();
                                String userProfilePicURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&method=GET&access_token=" + token;
                                String fullName = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                                String email = response.getJSONObject().optString("email");
                                String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
                                UserProfile.getInstance().setLoginProfileParams(names[0], names[1], userProfilePicURL, token);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                trace("json error " + e);
                            }
                        }

                    }
            ).executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically add the email field since Graph API v2.4, instead of only using `/me` you have to add the fields you want to get:

```
/me?fields=name,email
```

Of course that´s just the API call in its basic form, as you can read in the docs, you need to add the "fields" parameter as parameter in the "GraphRequest": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: Thanks for your input, but now I'm getting  {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}} and nothing I could find online is clear enough....or maybe I'm just dumb

Comment: you have to use an active access token, as the error message tells you. make sure the user is logged in.

Comment: I understand what the error message tells me, however I am giving it the AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); I also tried passing a params bundle containing an instance of the AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken, instead of null when doing the new GraphRequest.

Comment: AccessToken is all good...basically if I use "/me" I get a graphResponse containing {"id":"something", "name":"something"} and if I use "/me?fields=name,email" I get null response ... I'm slowly going crazy here

Comment: well, did you authorize the email permission and is it included in the access token?

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time for my struggle here. Im using this method for permission private void facebookLogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    }      I'm not sure about the last part though....being included in the access token

Comment: that looks good, now debug the access token in the debugger and make sure it includes the email permission

Comment: again, thanks for reaching out. There was no need for ?fields=name,email just using /me is working now as supposed to. Not knowing why is frustrating though :)

Comment: maybe you are using an older api version, but you definitely should add the fields as i suggested in my answer - else your app may stop working sooner or later.

Comment: Your answer is not only useless but also wrong, your sugestion is returning an error. I'm using facebook 4.5 and I guess you haven't looked around before posting your answer. I suggest you do a little research before shooting answers around.

Comment: it is THE answer, as you can read in the changelog. and it is the exact same answer in many other stackoverflow threads, because this question has been asked a lot. may i ask what error you get exactly? why do people never INCLUDE the error instead of just saying "there is an error"?...lol...btw, there is no "facebook 4.5", there are only sdk versions and api versions. the difference is very important.

Comment: i am not posting answers unless i am 100% sure they are true, btw. so please don´t tell me i should do some research. you are using the /me endpoint without declarative fields, so you don´t get the email. it´s very simple and very well known. if you would have done a tiny amount of research on your own, you would know about declarative fields ;)

Comment: btw, i assume you just used the api call as it is. i´ve added a link to the docs, of course you have to add the fields parameter as parameter of GraphRequest (you are using "null" right now).

Comment: again you are not paying attention, I posted the error first thing when I used your answer, the error says "An active token must be used..." which isn't the case if I don't use fields, which (as I stated in the "answer") is now returning the email as well. You may consider your answers are 100% correct, which is generally bad practice, but you have to answer based on the question circumstances, and I think you rush those up. Again, I thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87276/discussion-between-doru-chidean-and-luschn).